# Subtracting two columns inside lists of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subtraction, subscript

I have a list of dataframes which contains 10 columns of data and one empty column where I would like to have 'column 5 - column 10'. I have tried:

`lapply(GraphData, function(x){ x[,11] <- x[,5] - x[,10]})`

and

`GrpahData[,11] <- GraphData[,5] - GraphData[,10]`

However I am getting this error:

> x[, 5] : subscript out of bounds

and

> GraphData[, 5] : incorrect number of dimensions
>   respectively.

I suspect the issue is that some of the rows don't have a value for both columns, is there a good way to tell the code to ignore these rows

[An example of the data as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhaAD.png)

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you

[A part of str(GraphData) AS REQUESTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlnlM.png)

Comment: Can you post the `str(GraphData)`

Answer (score 0):

We need to return the 'x' i.e. the dataset.  In the OP's output, it is only the assigned column output is returned

```
lapply(GraphData, function(x){ x[,11] <- x[,5] - x[,10]; x})
```

Comment: still getting the subscript out of bound error with this

Comment: @NatashaJones your post says `have a list of dataframes which contains` So I am assuming that 'GraphData' is a list of data.frames

Comment: yes it is a list of data.frames as explained in the question

Comment: @NatashaJones do you get error with your first line of code `lapply(GraphData, function(x){ x[,11] <- x[,5] - x[,10]})`

Comment: Yes both options detailed in the question and your option above all get an error

Comment: @NatashaJones would it be okay to show a small example with `dput` to get the structure of the data or perhaps `str(GraphData)`

Comment: I have just added a photo of one of the dataframes from the list in the orignal post

Comment: @NatashaJones Please show the `str(GraphData)` so that I get the structure correctly

Comment: I have, added a part of this

Comment: @NatashaJones  Based on the `str`, I find 11 columns `data.frame` as `list` element and I think the above code should work on that given that the columns are numeric.  Is there any `list` element having less number of column i.e. `sapply(GraphData, ncol)` should all be more than 10

Comment: all the dataframes have the same number of columns and rows. I really do think that the NAs involved are the problem like I said in the question, do you have any advice on how to get the code to ignore rows with NAs

Comment: @NatashaJones `NA` have no issue here because any value difference with NA result in `NA` and not an error i.e. `1 - NA`

Comment: right that makes sense. Everything I try I am getting this "subscript out of bounds" error do you have any other suggestions

Comment: @NatashaJones  Can you try the code on a subset of GraphData, I think the problem is is one of hte list elements

Comment: @NatashaJones Can you test `lapply(GraphData[1:2], function(x){ x[,11] <- x[,5] - x[,11]; x})`

Comment: yeah if I seperate one dataframe I can do the maths but this doesn't really help as this is a completely different code 

trial <- GraphData[[1]]

trial[,11] <- trial[,5] - trial[,10]

Comment: @NatashaJones  Can you try `lapply(GraphData, function(x){ x[,11] <- x[[5]] - x[[,10]]; x})

Comment: yeah you are correct that works so it's just one of the dataframes which is different some how

Comment: that last one doesn't work. Im not too sure what you were trying with that either.

Comment: I am just going to apply the second to last one you sent to more and more of the dataframes until it errors and I can see which dataframe is the problem

Comment: I think it is one of the data.frame having some weird issue.  Can you use a `tryCatch`

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would update this if anyone wanted, the code let me apply the code

`lapply(GraphData[1:168], function(x){ x[,11] <- x[,5] - x[,11]; x})`

to all of the data.frames as long as I used the [1:168] without this it didn't work